# Magento 2 Mageplaza LayeredNavigation filter condition AND instead of OR for multiselect

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, porto-theme, mageplaza

I am working on a site that uses Mageplaza Layered Navigation in Porto Theme.

I need to change the behavior of multiselect from OR to AND.

As an example, I create attribute color. When I search for blue and red, it should only show products that are blue AND red.

Multiselect is correctly set, the only problem is to change the code - I cannot find where should I change.

Comment: Are you using LayeredNavigation Ultimate or Free?

Comment: I am using Free !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make multi-select with AND behaviour in Mageplaza LayeredNavigation, you will have to edit `initObserve` function of `app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/layer.js`  where you have to set the logic for allowing to select multiple links(passing multiple values in url for example:  base url/category url?color=51,49 ) & then to edit collection you have to set logic in `public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)` of
`app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` file for attributes, Similarly for category edit `app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`, for price

`app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php` & for decimal type edit `app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php/Decimal.php`

Comment: It looks like you solved the puzzle :) Thank you very much for your help !!!!

Comment: Thank You @GustavoUlyssea :)

Answer (score 1):

in the class Attribute when I filter:

```
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), ["finset" => $filters]);
```

with elasticsearch mode, I have the following error:
{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[terms] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [finset]","line":1,"col":228}

What could be causing the error?
Thanks

Comment: If it's answer describe more.